# Apache : How to print value of MaxRequestsPerChild in log files

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to troubleshoot some issue and need to print out the value of MaxRequestsPerChild in the log file. I set LogLevel to debug but it does not print out the value. Does anyone know how I can print this value out ?

Comment: That's a static value, why do you want to print it ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the hard way but creating a test environment and sending high number of requests to it and checking the number of processes.

I am not marking this as an answer. I would still like to know if displaying this information in the log files is possible.